# Application icon doesn't appear when I uninstall my app

Tags: android, icons, manifest, uninstallation

I dont know a lot of English, but I have a big problem. I install my application and I can see the application icon when I look for it, but when I go to the uninstall menu, or in the notification bar, the icon doesnt appear.
Here are some photos of that problem.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/h80w3ztp9ex36rw/2013-12-09%2020.56.03.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v69il8ai5oinkvm/2013-12-09%2000.44.58.png

I can write my AndroidManifest, it's this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.Podometro"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name="com.Podometro.HiScreen"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity 
             android:name="com.Podometro.Pedometer" 
             android:launchMode="singleTask"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             android:exported="true"
             > 
             </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.Podometro.CrearArchivo" 
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"> </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.Podometro.Twitear" 
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"> </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.Podometro.TwitterWebActivity" 
                   android:screenOrientation="portrait"> </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.Podometro.Constants_Settings" > </activity>


          <service android:enabled="true"
                 android:name="com.Podometro.TheService">
        </service>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
</manifest>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is that uninstaller but I'd make sure to check it doesn't happen with other applications too.
Also verify you've got a version of your icon for all standard size versions. (drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, etc.)

Buena suerte ;)

Comment: With other applications, this problem doesn't appear. I have all standard size version of the icon in their folders, but it doesn't work. This uninstaller is the MIUI uninstaller of every app.

I have some applications compiled with the same Eclipse and I can see the icon in all of them, but in this I can't. Thanks for your help, RoyalDroid.

Here is another photo of my problem, in the Notification bar.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/itch1p5ksr0iblw/2013-12-09%2000.44.29.png

Comment: Does this still reproduce after uninstalling completely > installing again > trying to uninstall?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work after that. I have cleaned the mobile cache. In another phone, with android 2.3, I can see the icon when I uninstall

Comment: Well, it sure would help more having the project and the phone, or any knowledge about MIUI known issues. However, I recommend you to compare with a working project for any missing implementations or mistakes you might have in your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have fixed it creating a new proyect, and copying and pasting all the items on the new one. I think that this problem is solved.