# android dev - changed ic_laucher but doesn't appear when running

Tags: android, icons

I deleted the standard android robot icon ic_launcher and added mine ( in various densities) 
and I have already in may manifest.xml

```
    <application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    ....
```

but after clean/build when running I still have the tiny android robot in my ActionBar and my app launch icon is still the  android default app robot icon ..

I guess I miss some additional parameter ??

my manifest file is surely wrong...
indicated by the colors....   drawable icon should be blue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling the app from the device and re-installing it to see the icon changes.

Yeah, the Application tag in your manifest file should set the icon like this:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: did it , no change ... even on the 2 testing devices I am using...
I generated the icons using the http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio , got the ic_launcher in all densities , deleted the existing ones ( robots) then imported corresponding new ic_launcher new icons ...  now way keep displaying the robot ...

Comment: Try looking into your resource folders (/drawable-hdpi, /drawable-ldpi, etc). Make sure you don't have any of your old icon in any of those folders either.

Comment: checked it .... all are OK new icon ... 
saw this post ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479574/application-icon-doesnt-appear-when-i-uninstall-my-app?rq=1
something else is wrong .. but I don't want to recreate and copy/paste the project (quite bif now...)

Comment: I changed the launcher icon in my HelloWorld test project and it works ... (wo changing any code..)  so the icons are good ... will try to delete and import them again...

Comment: Yeah, if you have your android:icon setup, then you don't need any more code changes. This is usually a cache problem, so doing a project -> clean and completely reinstalling the app should work. Also forgetting to remove the icons from other drawable folders could explain this. Other than that, there's nothing much left to do.

Comment: I guess I found the issue comparing both Manifest files...  my app manifest seems to be wrong .. will update my question ....

Comment: I should have look at the colors of your first answer..... you were right .. the manifest file was wrongly written... but as I did not get any error.. I did not look into it

Answer (score 0):

it was an error in my xml file....

```
    <application
    android:name="SwimmerApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, solved it after copying the `ic_launcher.png` to the `drawable-mdpi` folder under the `res`.